# Does this integral converge and can it be solved or approximated analytically?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, indefinite-integrals

I have the following integral:

$Q=\int_{t=T_2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{Ke^{-A(T+t)}\left(1-\frac{1}{(CG-1)(-1+(-1+e^{At})(F-1)G}\right)}{1+(-1+e^{-A(T+t)})F}\right)dt$, where $0<C<1$, $0<F \leq 1$, $0<G \leq 1$, and $A,K,T, T_2>0$.

Is there a way to show whether this integral converges? If so, can this integral be solved analytically? Perhaps using an approximation of some sort?

Thus far, I have found that the limit of $Q$ as $t \rightarrow 0$ is $\frac{-CGK}{(e^{AT}(F-1)-F)(CG-1)}$ and as $t \rightarrow \infty$ is zero.

I have tried simply solving the integral with WolframOnline, but the computation exceeds the time limit for my plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *Mathematica*:

```
(Integrate[k Exp[-a (t + tt)] (1 - 1/((c g - 1) (-1 + (-1 + Exp[a t]) (f - 1) g)))/
  (1 + f (-1 + Exp[-a (t + tt)])), {tt, t2, \[Infinity]},
  Assumptions -> {0 < c < 1, 0 < f <= 1, 0 < g <= 1, a > 0, t > 0, t2 > 0, k > 0}]) /. 
{a -> A, c -> C, f -> F, g -> G, t2 -> T2, t -> T}
```

$$\frac{k \left(1-\frac{1}{(C G-1) \left((F-1) G \left(e^{A T}-1\right)-1\right)}\right) \left(\log \left(e^{A (T+\text{T2})}-\frac{F}{F-1}\right)-A (T+\text{T2})\right)}{A F}$$

The last replacement part `{a -> A, c -> C, f -> F, g -> G, t2 -> T2, t -> T}` is because one should avoid using uppercase letters to start variable names in *Mathematica* and that use of that replacement rule was only to match the original variable names without having to edit the LaTeX code by hand.

Comment: Thank you so much!!